# Ternary operator only running first part of condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I am having trouble getting a count condition to work. Currently, whether I upload one or more than one file, the first condition where "Multiple files were" is running. The second part is never running.

Is there something else I have to do to get the second part of the condition to run if only one file has been uploaded?

```
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filename = $fu->upload();
$out = (count($filename) ? 'Multiple files were' : 'A file was'). '  uploaded. You can download ' . (count($filename) ? 'them' : 'the file'). ' from:</ul>';
```

Comment: why are you using ternaries like this? Ternary statements are meant to reduce lines of code that could still be readable via ternary.. this is 100% not readable - use full syntax for if statements..

Comment: The manual says: ***Note:

It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious***

Comment: @Andreas So, should I turn this into a normal if statement?

Comment: That is entirely up to you. If you can live with wrong messages being displayed then keep it as it is. But if you want readable and reliable code then change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is faulty.

`count($filename)` resolves to truthy if it's any value other than 0.

So whether it's 1 file or 64, that first part will always resolve to true. You need:

```
count($filename) > 1 ?
```